# Working with objects on android

Tags: android, json, memory-management, gson

I've started with android weeks ago, now I'm developing an app that get json data from a Web server store in an object and sometimes post data back. Very simple. 
Usage example.

Activity 1: ask user for postal code, get it from Web server using http async client from Apache, store in an object using gson and put this object in an Intent to the next action.

Activity 2: show address data, from the retrieved intent object, and wait for the user fill a complementary field with his number. Finally this data is posted back to server.

Activity 3: a json with a list of restaurants are received as response an again using gson this data is stored as `List<restaurants>` and iterate through this list to render the data into the view setting id's and tags.

Everything is ok until I start debug my code. Watching the memory usage I saw that it was increasing very fast reaching 10mb. If I back to postal code Activity and do it again, more memory are allocated

I've search about, and in an android document about tips for memory usage and on a Google IO video about android memory I've figured out that objects are not a good choice. 
So, how do I do to work with json data lists or use objects correctly to manage my data? I came from Web development based on getters / setters OO based development.

Comment: What about objects with getters/setters?? 

Should I use onlu public static attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Besides few primitive data types (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `char`, `boolean`) everything in Java is an object. You cannot avoid using objects.

What you can do is to make sure that you don't keep references to objects you no longer need. For everything else you are at mercy of GC.